# How to call multiple URLs in single service in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, jdbc

```
DBConn dBConn = new DBConn();
PreparedStatement prepareStatement;

Connection con = dBConn.getDBConnectionForPro();
prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TBL_MASCONFIGTTB WHERE SERVICE_NAME=GUPSHUP AND VALUE=TRUE");

if (prepareStatement.equals("true")) {
    System.out.println(GenerateLinkDaoImpl.sendOTP("90xxxxxxxx", smsBody));
}
else {
    System.out.println(GenerateLinkDaoImpl.SendSms("90xxxxxxxx", smsBody));
}
```

Comment: You can use multi threading to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean call multiple URLs ?

Comment: Hello and welcome on stack overflow! Your code seems functionnal to me, perhaps you could add some info on the functionality you are trying to implement?

Comment: Why do you think `prepareStatement.equals("true")` would ever evaluate to `true`? `prepareStatement` is a `PreparedStatement`, so it will never be equal to the String `"true"`. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use boolean on PreparedStatement you need to use ResultSet first.
try using below code.

```
DBConn dBConn = new DBConn();
PreparedStatement prepareStatement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

Connection con = dBConn.getDBConnectionForPro();
prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TBL_MASCONFIGTTB WHERE SERVICE_NAME=GUPSHUP AND VALUE=TRUE");
rs = prepareStatement.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(GenerateLinkDaoImpl.sendOTP("90xxxxxxxx", smsBody));
}
else {
    System.out.println(GenerateLinkDaoImpl.SendSms("90xxxxxxxx", smsBody));
}
```